# Nested structs and unions with Common Lisp CFFI

Tags: common-lisp, zeromq, ffi

I want to write a small wrapper library for a C library (ZeroMQ v3, to be more specific).

I wonder, however, how to declare foreign nested structs and unions in CFFI.

The C header file containing the respective struct/union combination can be found [here](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/blob/master/include/zmq.h#L293).

CFFI's documentation couldn't help so far and I also couldn't find similar questions online yet.

I'll be glad for any help!

Comment: Before you do that, take a look at [lisp-zmq](https://github.com/galdor/lisp-zmq) and [cl-zmq](http://www.cliki.net/cl-zmq)

Comment: I did that already. As said in my question, I'm explicitly targeting ZeroMQ *v3* only, which is supported neither by lisp-zmq nor cl-zmq. I personally think new projects should be started with the latest stable version of libraries. That is why I want to port lisp-zmq to ZeroMQ v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defcstruct` can be used in this case. Also, in the [docs](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/defcstruct.html) you'll find examples of defining a foreign struct, and also that the two kinds of slots possible are simple (types such as `:int`) and aggregate (the name of other struct), so nothing prevents you to be defining the different structures that form that big union and then compose the union (there is also a `defcunion` construct).

The own CFFI implementation has examples and tests for structs like this:

```
(defcstruct s-short
  (a-char :char)
  (another-char :char)
  (a-short :short))

(defcstruct s-s-short
  (yet-another-char :char)
  (a-s-short s-short))
```

Note that `a-s-short` is of type `s-short`, defined above.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar idea in mind, but I was not sure whether this approach would be the most elegant. I was wondering if I could find a solution close to the C code, even if less flexible (e.g. nesting the defc* macros).